# Is SMS to computer possible?

Tags: sms, transfer

I have a nokia lumia 900, and when I am working on the computer I would like to receive my sms messages on my computer rather than having to stop what I'm doing to check my phone. Plus it's just faster to type on a computer keyboard.

This question is much like https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4738/6705, but this is for android and not windows. Any ideas?

Comment: The closest you can do is something as outlined here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/people/send-a-text-message.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading messages on your computer I don't think there is a way to do this currently. [This](http://www.xda-developers.com/windows_phone/smsbackup-backs-up-text-messages-on-wp7/) might be of some help but it only accesses messages older than 1 day and it requires a phone to be interop unlocked, so no chance of getting it into the marketplace.

For composing the messages you should look at SMSComposeTask. This allows you to open the Text Messaging application and set the "To" and "Message" field. Once your app sets those fields you'd just have to hit the send button. So that's half the problem sorted. You just need to figure out a way to get your computer to talk to your phone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah and before root comes out for my phone I don't know if this will be possible... But I'll take a look at it, thanks for the input!

Comment: The way things are right now, I think being able to read the messages on the computer is out which is a pity. Being able to write the message on the computer would be cool though. I could write the same message on my computer 10 quicker than on my phone. I imagine it could be accomplished with a web service. I really hope WP8 opens more things like this up and let us do more with it.

Comment: Yeah I fully agree with you there. The windows phone has great potential, they just need a bit more flexibility

Comment: Windows Phone 8 will have built in automatic SMS backup to PC or Cloud. Hang in there a little longer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can switch your number to a Google voice number and then redirect SMS to your phone or computer depending on the time of day

Comment: That is a pretty good suggestion. Thanks, and welcome to WinPhone.SE!

Comment: You don't have to redirect the SMS. There is an option in Google Voice to have a copy of the message sent over email. You can reply to the email and it will go out as an SMS as well.